# multithreaded BlockingQueue - add at the head

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, java.util.concurrent

I have a problem with `BlockingQueue`.

It is working for me when I use it as the queue. However, sometimes I would like to return several tasks to the queue to the head.

I assume `BlockingQueue` is not able to do that operation.

Is any other structure is able to do that and is ThreadSafe? I would like to avoid `Collections.synchronizedList()` but I do not have any idea how to implement such problem with `java.utils.concurrent` possibilities?

Any hints which structure is able to support such a problem in multi-threaded environment, please?

Comment: By 'the end where I am taking the messages', you want to make sure that those messages are taken first. I would call it the 'head' of the queue.

Comment: Fair point @GreyFairer. Corrected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a [BlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html)? `addLast` doesn't block and adds to tail and `putLast` blocks and adds to tail.

Comment: You have right @Jason - so close to each other and I didn't notice - sorry for the problem. I use `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Don't even fret, it's a valid question! You also expressed the question quite well so good job.